# automate repetitive internet connection process with a bash script: for Arch Linux

Tags: bash, arch-linux

each time I log onto my computer and want to access the internet I need to type in the following commands:

```
ip l
```

w<sub>b</sub>

then I see something like:

```
all the interfaces...
enp0s20u2
```

*or*

```
...
enp0s20u1
```

then I need to type:

```
sudo dhcpcd enp0s20u2
```

(or possibly `enp0s20u1`)

then type in my `sudo` password, and then I'm connected

It's annoying to do this repetitive process over and over, all the time.

Could I automate this process with a bash script, such that I just call it, and then it's done?

What would such a script look like? What must it include? Where should I store it?

Comment: [Using Bash script to edit config file](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=115348)

Comment: You should look before `man interfaces`

Comment: For this particular case, `dhcpcd` can probe the available interfaces on its own, if you don't provide any on the command line. Also, you should probably be starting `dhcpcd` through the init system, rather than doing it manually. If it's a recent Arch, something like `systemctl enable dhcpcd; systemctl start dhcpcd` should work.

Comment: If your issue is actually changing network device names, [set a persistent device name](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration#Device_names)...

Answer (score 1):

Tom Hunt's comment should already answer your question, but just in case your `dhcpcd` is unable to probe the available interfaces on its own (which is already a problem), you can write a simple one-liner like this:
`sudo dhcpcd $(ip l | sed -n 's/.*\(enp0s20u[0-9]*\):.*/\1/p')`

You can then save this line into a file and call it whenever you want. This is not satisfactory though, as this type of initialization should be done automatically when you log in.

Comment: can't I put this into some file then that loads itself when I log in?

Comment: Stick it in `.profile` in your `~`